# How do I get latitude and longitude in google map api v2?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to build an android app which shows the present location of the device. So far I get the location in the map (using GPS) and able to show the present location. Now I want to put a marker there, but I'm unable to find the value of latitude and longitude so that I can pass it to the

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
```

PS: I'm beginner in android development so please explain and I'm using android studio.

Answer (score 2):

First use api `FusedLocationApi` to get `Latlng` and then just need to write a `handleNewLocation` method to handle the `LatLng`, and add the marker on your map.

Sample code:

```
private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("I am here!");
        mMap.addMarker(options);
}
```

For the `whole project` of `source code`, please refer my github [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/getLastLocationUsingGPS-android), you `can clone it and try it` and it will meet your requirement.

Please feel free to reach out to me in case you have any further questions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

what I did was implement com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,OnConnectionFailedListener.
create a GoogleApiClient Field and call the below method from onCreate

```
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "buildGoogleApiClient", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

As your activity implemented above interfaces you will have the below methods and from onConnected you can get current location

```
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "in onconnected of location services",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

}
```

you can use mLastLocation.getLatitude and .getLongitude